# How to set env variable from gitlab ci cd dynamically

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I would like to edit the [gitlab cicd variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4KLL.png) thru my pipeline script.

Flow:

1. Submit merge request
2. CI pipeline retrieve the version number (variable stored in the CICD project setting (refer to pic although the variable version is not included)
3. version+1 and set back into the CICD project setting
4. git tag the file based on version number

the file i want to git tag is a bash script file and I am using Linuxx docker image. please advise

current script

```
variables: 
  PROFILE_NAME: default

default:
  image: docker-image

stages: 
  - tagging

Tag:
  stage: tag
  script:
    - yum install git -y
    - git --version 
    - git remote set-url --push origin ${CI_SERVER_PROTOCOL}://${GITLAB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME}:${GITLAB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}.git
    - export "VERSION=$(($VERSION +1 ))" > $INC_VERSION
    - echo 'after version:' $VERSION
    - echo 'after increment version:' $INC_VERSION
    - git push origin --tags
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_requests
    variables:
      - ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^dev/ || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^dev/ || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^release-/ || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^release-/)
  except:
    variables:
      - ($CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA == '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000' && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME !~ /^./)
```

Comment: Changing an environment variable during a job run won't change the *source* of the value. You'd need to use [GitLab's API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html#update-variable) for this.

Comment: @slauth so is it possible for me to incorporate this into my script? As i am new to this

Comment: Yes, that's possible.